# Integrate B&W & color cameras

Tags: camera

I have a T14 Thinkpad with "Hybrid Infrared (IR) & HD720p with ThinkShutter". That is, it actually has 2 cameras. One for B&W and one for color. Same as in mobile phones.

The builtin `cheese` app can't combine their outpots (to get better image). Is there something I can do? Are there apps that do combine?